# ¿Cómo guardar los datos que va calculando un doble bucle for en una tabla? R

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe del siguiente estilo:

```
Entrega Solicitante Cantidad.entrega Peso.total Volumen Material
1 8592709797         798                4      52.80  94.100     1090
2 8592709797         798                5      22.00  30.265     2012
3 8592709797         798               25      33.00 470.650     2993
4 8592709797         798                2      16.32  28.504     3212
5 8592709797         798                1      12.60  23.525     2627
6 8592709797         798                2      20.80  30.802     1996
              Denominación Num_transporte      Fecha week
      COCA-COLA PET50 C24       18764702 2020-08-03   32
     COCA-COLA LATA33 P12       18764702 2020-08-03   32
     COCA-COLA LATA20 P6.       18764702 2020-08-03   32
 COCA-COLA PET1,25L P2 C3       18764702 2020-08-03   32
  COCA-COLA ZER PET50 C24       18764702 2020-08-03   32
   COCA-COLA ZER VNR1L C6       18764702 2020-08-03   32
               Nombre                Dirección   Localidad Código.Provincia
LECLERC MAJADAHONDA PLANTIO-MAJADAHONDA  S/N MAJADAHONDA                M
 LECLERC MAJADAHONDA PLANTIO-MAJADAHONDA  S/N MAJADAHONDA                M
 LECLERC MAJADAHONDA PLANTIO-MAJADAHONDA  S/N MAJADAHONDA                M
 LECLERC MAJADAHONDA PLANTIO-MAJADAHONDA  S/N MAJADAHONDA                M
 LECLERC MAJADAHONDA PLANTIO-MAJADAHONDA  S/N MAJADAHONDA                M
 LECLERC MAJADAHONDA PLANTIO-MAJADAHONDA  S/N MAJADAHONDA                M
  Código.Postal  Latitud Longitud   Distrito1   Distrito2
       28220 40.47517 -3.84956 MAJADAHONDA MAJADAHONDA
       28220 40.47517 -3.84956 MAJADAHONDA MAJADAHONDA
       28220 40.47517 -3.84956 MAJADAHONDA MAJADAHONDA
       28220 40.47517 -3.84956 MAJADAHONDA MAJADAHONDA
       28220 40.47517 -3.84956 MAJADAHONDA MAJADAHONDA
       28220 40.47517 -3.84956 MAJADAHONDA MAJADAHONDA
```

Quiero crear un bluce for para calcular el número de vehículos (num de Num_transporte distintos) por semana y por código postal.

He creado un doble bucle for de la siguiente forma:

```
for (i in week){
  for(cp in Código.Postal){
  aux=length(unique(Num_transporte))
  }
}
```

Pero claro, al no haberle dicho al código que me guarde los datos, solo me mostrará el último valor.
Me gustaría guardar los que va calculando en una tabla que tuviese filas: Codigo Postal y columnas Semanas, y en cada entrada tenga el valor aux que corresponde a la semana i y el codigo postal cp.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método que propones es poco eficiente, sobre todo con datos más grandes. Aunque no sea lo más recomendable, con el doble bucle, una posible solución sería:

```
week <- unique(dt$week)
resumen <- data.frame(semana = as.integer(),
                      cp = as.integer(), 
                      aux = as.integer())
for (i in week) {
  x <- subset(dt, week == i)
  Código.Postal <- unique(x$Código.Postal)
  for (cp in Código.Postal) {
    y <- subset(x, Código.Postal == cp)
    aux <- length(unique(y$Num_transporte))
    resumen[nrow(resumen) + 1, ] <- c(i, cp, aux) 
  }
}
```

Con R base, sin el uso de librerías adicionales puedes utilizar la función [aggregate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate) que realiza el tipo tarea que necesitas sin el uso de bucles y con una sintaxis mucho más clara.

```
resumen2 <- aggregate(Num_transporte ~ week + Código.Postal, length, data = dt)
```

No obstante, te recomiendo el uso de la librería dplyr y el uso de pipes %>%. El código se hace mucho más eficiente y la sintaxis más clara.

```
library(tidyverse)

resumen3 <- dt %>% 
  group_by(week, Código.Postal) %>% 
  summarise(aux = length(unique(Num_transporte)))
```

Si nunca has utilizado dplyr puedes empezar con algo básico como https://mauricioanderson.com/curso-r-dplyr/